# How to display registration form fields based on the taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I have three taxonomy terms. And I want to display different fields in the registration form based on the taxonomy term.

I want something like this.

taxonomy term 1:
Registration form fields: Name, Email, Password, City, phone

taxonomy term 2:
Registration form fields: Name, Email, Password, Country

taxonomy term 3:
Registration form fields: Name, Email, Password, State, phone

Is it possible? if yes then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 7 you've a new API named [State API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7). You can use it to hide or show your fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try with combination of two module.

1. [field_collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)
2. [conditional_fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)